# tensorflow-0.8.0-cp35-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: scripts

`tensorflow-0.8.0-cp35-none-linux_x86_64.whl` is not a supported wheel on this platform.

This is the error it is showing when I am trying to install `tensorflow` on Ubuntu 16.04. Can you please help me remove this error?

Comment: Some info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622613/tensorflow-installation-error-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40941015/tensorflow-on-windows-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform-error . Please edit and update you question with at least the Ubuntu release/version you're running.

Comment: Also, tell us more about how you're trying to install it. There are five methods given on `tensorflow's` site: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup

Comment: When trying $ pip install tensorflow on 16.04 here, it starts with : Downloading tensorflow-0.12.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (43.1MB) which seems like a much newer version than your 0.8.x  and it intstalls fine without any errors. The Pip install should be one of the easiest installs in general.